# Clip raster not working: no target filename specified QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, clip

I know this topic has been covered before but I didn't find an answer to my problem so far...
I've been trying to clip a raster unsuccessfully with canvas extent or with mask layer. It ever works and I always get the same message: `"no target filename specified"` or `"no target data specified"`. With the specific message

> *Loading resulting layers The following layers were not correctly generated.
>
> - C:/Users/LongNhi
>   Computer/Documents/1.tif
>
> You can check the 'Log Messages
> Panel' in QGIS main window to find more information about the
> execution of the algorithm. QGIS version: 3.12.0-București FAILURE: No
> target filename specified.
>
> Usage: gdalwarp [--help-general] [--formats]
>  [-s_srs srs_def]
> [-t_srs srs_def] [-to "NAME=VALUE"]* [-novshiftgrid]
>  [-order n |
> -tps | -rpc | -geoloc] [-et err_threshold]
>  [-refine_gcps tolerance [minimum_gcps]]
>  [-te xmin ymin xmax ymax] [-tr xres yres] [-tap]
> [-ts width height]
>  [-ovr level|AUTO|AUTO-n|NONE]
>  [-wo
> "NAME=VALUE"] [-ot Byte/Int16/...] [-wt Byte/Int16]
>  [-srcnodata
> "value [value...]"] [-dstnodata "value [value...]"] -dstalpha
>  [-r
> resampling_method] [-wm memory_in_mb] [-multi] [-q]
>  [-cutline
> datasource] [-cl layer] [-cwhere expression]
>  [-csql statement]
> [-cblend dist_in_pixels] [-crop_to_cutline]
>  [-of format] [-co
> "NAME=VALUE"]* [-overwrite]
>  [-nomd] [-cvmd meta_conflict_value]
> [-setci] [-oo NAME=VALUE]
>  *[-doo NAME=VALUE]*
>  srcfile*
> dstfile*

My manip is the following, I'm a beginner in QGIS and I've been trying to solve it but nothing works. Anyone has an idea about what could I do?

[image]

Comment: Very first I would try to use filepath with no spaces.

Comment: thank you I tried but it doesn't work neither. I tried to put it in a temporary file as wel and the message is still ' no dataset target specified"